# Unable to create SavedModel from keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to follow the guide found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#export_to_savedmodel), but it just saves the model as a file instead of as a folder as the tutorial outlines.

Code:

```
import segmentation_models as sm
from keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf

path_to_model = "models/unet_70.h5"
loss = sm.losses.binary_focal_dice_loss
model = load_model(path_to_model, custom_objects={'binary_focal_loss_plus_dice_loss': loss})

model.save('model')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from a difference between the [Keras](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/) api and the api for Keras running on top of [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#export_to_savedmodel).

To achieve the desired effect, you can change the module you import from

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```